# Error when making predictions on un-pickled classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, pickle

I am making a text classifying program which has input of over thousand emails, so for convenience I have decided to save the classifier in a pickled file after the training is complete, so that after further executions of the program, I wont have to retrain it.

```
path = 'classifier.pkl'
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
if not os.path.exists(path):
    # making a classifier
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(clf, f)
else:
    print('<classifier found!>')
    input_file = open(path, 'rb')
    clf = pickle.load(input_file)
    input_file.close()
pred = clf.predict(x_test) # the error occurs on this line
```

The prediction works on first run (when classifier is not a file input). But it gives me this error on next executions:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (3516,379) (376,)

shapes of x_train and x_test are as follows: (14062, 379), (3516, 379)

Any help would be appreciated

Edit: I have tried desertnaut's suggestion of pickling `pred = clf.predict(x_test)` and using it in further runs of the program, and accuracy score I get from those runs seem to be twice as low as the score when initially training the classifier

Comment: Your question is quite unclear; what do you mean "on first run (when classifier is not a file input)"? Does the classifier work OK with the same input *before* pickling it?

Comment: No, I mean that it works when first training the classifier, before pickling it (when if statement is executed). When else statement is executed program gives me mentioned error

Comment: First thing to try, then, should be to add `clf.predict(x_test)` inside the `if` statement, so that you see if the problem is with pickling or with your `xtest` (it seems that it is the latter indeed)...

Comment: I will try that, but I do not understand why this program does not work, I have used exact same code in other classifiers and they work just fine. Edit: pickling the prediction and then un-pickling it does seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not figure out why pickling does not work. However, sklearn's joblib function seems to work just fine.

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
if not os.path.exists(path):
    clf = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    joblib.dump(clf, path)
else:
    clf = joblib.load(path)
```